# image background not show

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

i have an image background for my web....it's a JPG file.. my problem is that image not show at designer PC but after that web page open at another PC..the image can show..i created my program at terminal...

i try using chmod 777 image.jpg but at designer PC still can't show...but in other PC can show..why it happens??what must i do?

Comment: at least i do not understand what you are trying to say. your webpage contains a background image, which is not displayed on some machines?

Comment: image background not show at server PC but at client PC it can show...

Comment: is this essentially the same problem as http://superuser.com/questions/159247/programs-item-not-show-at-linux-ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just guessing from the mini bits of information you provide:

when you specify a filename on windows, it does not matter (essentially) if you mix upper and lower characters. on unix this matters.

example:

your image is called "FoObAr.jPG"

on windows you can reference it in any variation of:

- "foobar.jpg"
- "FOOBAR.JPG"
- "foobar.JPG"

on unix there is only ONE valid form:

- "FoObAr.jPG"

so, check the filename of your image and use EXACTLY that filename. furthermore, do not use `\` in paths, use `/` (for example if you do something like src="..\images\foo.JPG" ... )